# Time frame in a second conditional clause

Tags: conditional-constructions

In type 1 conditional sentences, the time is the present or future and the situation is real in both clauses.
In type 3 conditionals, the time is the past in both clauses.
In Type 2 conditionals, the main clause time frame is now or future.

Question: I haven't seen any time frame mentioned in type 2 conditionals for the conditional (if) clause.

If I am constructing a mixed condition as in the examples:

1. *If he were my buddy, he would have helped me.*  (conditional clause 2nd conditional, main clause 3rd conditional)
2. *If I were not afraid of centipedes, I would not have shouted then.* (same mixed type as in the first example)

Now, as per my understanding, for the examples to be correct, the time frame in the conditional clause has to be **now or always**. This is because the main clause happened in the past which means he was not my buddy then. Similarly, I was afraid of centipedes then (in the past time when I shouted).

Please clarify and correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Main clause is not in the past but in unreality.  Paraphrase: If he is truly my friend he would have helped me.  Perhaps he is your enemy. But not a true friend.

Comment: If you want to speak of a past situation that was contrary to fact, you could say "If he had been my friend, he would have helped me."   If he and I had been friends *at the time*.

Comment: Our question is pertaining to typical mixed conditionals and the time frame of the conditional clause in the second conditional.  I know that 'were' in "If I were rich" is not past tense, but a distance from reality.  Yeah, what you have said in your second comment is third conditional ( things that did not happen or we say 'missed chances/oppertunities). I had mentioned the third conditionals at the start of my question..

Comment: "If  I won a lottery, I would go for a world tour." Here, the main clause has a time frame of now or future. I think the time frame for conditional seems like now or future (not sure). BUT  in the mixed conditional of my question, 'he would have helped me' is something that didn't happen in the past and it is pertaining to past. So what could be the time frame of  "If he were my buddy?" Shouldn't it be now or always?

Comment: All if clauses are suppositions; they are not "real". And in conditional, there is only **a past conditional**. In the second conditional: If I went, I would see him. went is not a past tense. It is a supposition. If he were my buddy, we wouldn't have these problems. Another example of that. Condition contrary to fact is a good way to remember it.

Comment: @Lambie Yeah,  in the case of the second conditional, it is either counterfactual or very less likely. Could you please address the time frame for the If clause in the second conditional of the example "If he were my buddy, he would have helped me." (The other example is identical grammatically.)

Comment: Your example " If he were my buddy, we wouldn't have these problems" is a type 2 conditional. (Not mixed). Could you please look into the mixed conditional examples that I have given in the question and address the time frame? What I am saying is, that it is not enough that the real FACT is "he is not my buddy NOW". As the 3rd conditional main clause part says about a past thing ( he would have helped) doesn't it require that the FACT is "he was not my buddy then." If I am not clear still, I think we should leave this here. :)

Comment: In every conditional, for both the if clause and the condition clause I have seen time frames applicable. (I have mentioned in the question) I don't see it in the second conditional condition clause part.

Answer (score 1):

Mixed conditional: If he were my buddy, he would have helped me. (conditional clause 2nd conditional, main clause 3rd conditional)

The supposition about "if he were my buddy" is a general supposition. Compare it to:

If he **had been** my buddy [which he is now], he would have helped me.

This is similar to:
"She said he *is* a nice man". [nice man is a general thing that continues to apply at all times. Compared to:
"She said he **was** a nice man" She said that he "was" that.

Comment: I agree and have upvoted. What we discussed is a second conditional counterfactual condition. Now, my understanding is that the time frame in the conditional clause of  "If I won a lottery, I would go for a world tour." (This example is not counterfactual and impossible, but very improbable)  is 'now or the future" as the little chance of winning the lottery cannot happen in the past.  Please clarify.

Comment: @brp7 The difference between If I win the lottery, I will go. etc. versus If I won the lottery, I would go. etc. is the degree of probability.

Comment: Yea. I am aware of that. (would is used as opposed to will for less possibility). Could you address the time frame in this condition as it is not counterfactual?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean at all.  If I won the lottery [but **I haven't.  so this is counterfactual**], I would go on a world tour. All conditionals **except past conditional** which expresses a counterfactual in the past.

Comment: "If  I won a lottery..." has a slight chance of occurrence in comparison with 'If I were you, I wouldn't do that." The second case is counterfactual (impossible) as I cannot be you. *************************************************************************************** Quoting: "The second conditional is used to imagine present or future situations that are impossible OR unlikely in reality. source: https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/grammar/b1-b2-grammar/conditionals-zero-first-second

Comment: @brp7 Right. You say them in the present time only, those two. See how they both say impossible? That's counterfactual/

Answer (score 0):

By definition, the Second Conditional implies a hypothetical situation in the **present** or **future** and its hypothetical result in the present/future.

> *If the weather was better* (now or generally)*, we could have a picnic.*

> *What would Bill do if there was an earthquake* (now or in future) *in the area?*

So, technically, you're right.

In fact, there're **2 types of Mixed Conditionals** and in both of them the 2-nd Conditional indicates the present time.

---

### Type I:

**Third Conditional (if-clause) + Second Conditional (main clause)**

**Usage:** Hypothetical conditions in the past and their results in the present.

> *If Bill had won the lottery, he wouldn't be playing with us* (now or "always" depending on the context)*.*

> *You might not be in so much trouble if you hadn't started gambling.*

### Type II:

**Second Conditional (if-clause) + Third Conditional (main clause)**

**Usage:** Hypothetical conditions in the present and their results in the past.

> *If Bill knew about computers, he would have applied for that job.*

> *I would have made Bill buy a lottery ticket if I were you.*

---

[conditionals](/questions/tagged/conditionals) [conditional-constructions](/questions/tagged/conditional-constructions)

Comment: Let us take your example. In that, the main clause says "he would have applied for that job" That is something in the past. That implies that Bill never knew about computers in the past as well.  If you take an example like " If I won a lottery," then the time frame is now or in the future ( as we can't win a lottery in the past). So putting both types of examples, what I infer is that the conditional clause time frame has to be "now or always." Hope you understand.

Comment: Yeah, the 2-nd conditional if-clause time frame can be described as "now or always", and in some scenarios, "in future". Ex: "If Bill had won the lottery, he would go and buy a car (in future)". However, in the example "If I won a lottery, I would ..." conditional clause doesn't really refer to the future but rather hypothetical current state of having won the lottery.

Comment: It's not a mistake. The sentence is grammatical. But if you want to refer to the future (you're anticipating winning a lottery or imagining how you win the lottery) I'd recommend using First Conditional: "If I win the lottery, I'll go on a world tour".

Comment: Oh you mean that. That is a typical type 2 sentence. I wanted to say that the time frame is now or the future as opposed to our initial question. An exact replica example would be "If I became the president, I would support green energy projects.  (It is improbable that I will become president.) The 'would' in type 2 as opposed to 'will' is used to show a very low chance of occurrence. Type 2 example 3. If I met my favourite actor, I would ask for a photo with her.  (It is improbable that I will meet my favourite actor.). In all the examples, it is NOT counterfactual but least probable.

Comment: Now I see… Yeah, that makes sense.